# Bs4 No tables are found

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In my code, I'm trying to scrape a table from a website, but no tables were output. I already checked the status code, and it has access to the site, the given table class should also be right, I have no idea please help

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests



url = f'https://sk1er.club/leaderboards/guild_level'

page = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', class_ = "table table-striped display dataTable")
print(page.status_code)
print(table)
```

Comment: What is the output you got and what was the output you would have expected?

Answer (score 1):

The table is loaded from https://sk1er.club/leaderboards/newdata/GUILD_LEVEL. Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://sk1er.club/leaderboards/newdata/GUILD_LEVEL'

page = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', class_ = "table table-striped display")
print(page.status_code)
print(table)
```

Comment: How can you see where the table is loaded from?

Comment: By inspecting the [network activity](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/).